# removing a space in a citation using BibTex

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I'm a BibTex neophyte, and this one problem is driving me crazy.  The .bst file I am modifying uses the number variable identically for both conference paper and journal citations, which is not what the journal I am submitting to wants (and no, they didn't provide a .bst file!).  So, I tried to modify the function for journal citations in the following way:

```
FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
{ volume field.or.null
  volume empty$
    'skip$
    { bbl.volume "~" * swap$ * }
  if$
  number empty$
    'skip$
    {
     ", ("  * number ")"  tie.or.space.connect *  
    volume empty$
        { "there's a number but no volume in " cite$ * warning$ }
           'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

This gives, for example:

> Strawn, R., Caradonna, F., and Duque, E., “30 Years of Rotorcraft Computational Fluid Dynamics Research and Development,” Journal of the American Helicopter Society, Vol. 51, (1 ), 2006, pp. 5–21.

Which is perfect, EXCEPT for the space after 1 in `(1 )!`  The editor won't accept the paper until this is fixed.  Please any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Does this happen with all citation or just with one/a few? The space might come in from the `.bib` file. Also BibTeX produces a `.bbl` file where you could manually delete the space if it is urgent.

Comment: It's in all of the citations (>100!)  I did verify that there were no extra spaces in the .bib file.

Comment: It is probably to late to change to [BibLaTeX](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex), isn't it?

Comment: Unfortunately it is too late to change unless there is a tool to convert my bib files to biblatex versions.  I guess if there is no easy answer, I can edit the .bbl by hand.  (UPDATE: It was actually a quick and easy fix in .bbl, I was able to do a replace all on "~)," to "),", which fixed them all, but left everything else alone!  Thanks for the help Martin - you're a life-saver!

Comment: You can use Search&Replace with almost every texteditor. If the journal editor request the LaTeX code copy the edited .bbl file to "references.tex" and `\input` that one in you document instead of using BibTeX. It's just a workaround but should "just do it".

Comment: It was actually a quick and easy fix in .bbl, I was able to do a replace all on "~)," to "),", which fixed them all, but left everything else alone! Thanks for the help Martin - you're a life-saver!

Comment: Ok, the `~` was probably there because the old style was *missing* a space after the number.

Comment: @Marylin: Fine that the problem solved! Because there's no real answer and the question is too localized, I will close it. Feel free to open another question if you would encounter another problem.